# parameter choosing for SIS based scheme in lattice based cryptography

Tags: lattice-crypto

In SIS based scheme, there is a  matrix  $A \stackrel{\$}{\leftarrow} \mathbb{Z}^{n\times m}_{q}$, and $n$ is the security parameter. I want to ask that why $n=1$ is also okay for the scheme (in "[A framework for building composable zero-knowledge proofs](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/1093.pdf)" the authors choose the following parameters for the Ajtai hash function, see the following picture). At this time, the security of the Ajtai hash function is based on the SVP problem with dimension 1.

- Is SVP with $n=1$  hard?
- And n is a small positive integer is also OK  for SIS based scheme in lattice-based cryptography?

[image]

I also see that "$n = 1024$, which is a typical choice for lattice-based schemes targeting medium or high-security levels" in the paper "[Blaze: practical lattice-based blind signature for privacy-preserving application"](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/1167.pdf).

- So how to explain this? I say that why there is a preference choosing for $n$？